# Alkenes express different reactivity with acids depending on concentration and temperature

Tags: organic-chemistry

The below images show when 1-butene reacts with different reagents (in d it's also H2SO4 not H2SO). My question is why are the two products different?

I can get that in c), because it's more dilute there's more water to act as the nucleophile, and in d) there's more H2SO4 so that would act as the nucleophile but what's the role of temperature?

[image]

Comment: If hot concentrated sulfuric acid were used it may cause the butene molecules to react with each other to form an ether or another possible compound due to the dehydrating properties, high reactivity and protic properties of the sulfuric acid. The reaction to form butanol at a specific temperature must need water to stop this occuring. The second product must require the sulfuric acid to be stronger , so to prevent a reaction between the butene molecules and favour the ester formation over the alcohol formation the reaction is cooled.